# etckeeper for opensuse - bash script install and configure

Tags: backup, git, etc

I want to automate the installation of [etckeeper](https://github.com/joeyh/etckeeper) on OpenSuse 12.3.

My first issue is that etckeeper doesn't seem to be available in the standard OpenSuse repos.

```
zypper search etckeeper
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
No packages found.
```

The second issue I anticipate is that when I use etckeeper manually I sometimes have to configure it (init) before it starts working. Here's the info about that from the readme:

> The `etckeeper init` command initialises an /etc/.git/ repository. 
>   If you installed etckeeper from a package, this was probably automatically
>   performed during the package installation. If not, your first step is to
>   run it by hand:

```
etckeeper init
```

I would like a script that will install it and have it init'd automatically with no end-user intervention required.

Comment: One reason for `etckeeper init` not to be performed automatically is to give you a chance to select your favorite VCS first (should it call `git init`, or `hg init`, or `bzr init`, or `darcs init`?).

Comment: @Gilles - that's a good point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, here's an answer, but it is not ideal. I was hoping to find an official OpenSuse package from one of the repos. But until someone suggests a better alternative, here's what I came up with:

1. find the package:
   http://software.opensuse.org/package/etckeeper
2. download it:
   wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Peuserik:/OSSFAC/openSUSE_12.3/noarch/etckeeper-1.3-2.1.noarch.rpm
3. install it:
   sudo zypper in etckeeper-1.3-2.1.noarch.rpm
4. initialize it:
   sudo etckeeper init

So the script would be:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Peuserik:/OSSFAC/openSUSE_12.3/noarch/etckeeper-1.3-2.1.noarch.rpm
sudo zypper in etckeeper-1.3-2.1.noarch.rpm
sudo mv /etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf /etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf.original
sudo tee /etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf > /dev/null << ENDDOC
HIGHLEVEL_PACKAGE_MANAGER=zypper
LOWLEVEL_PACKAGE_MANAGER=rpm
VCS="git"
ENDDOC #no space before this line
cd etc
sudo etckeeper init
sudo git commit -m "initial checkin"
sudo git gc # pack git repo to save a lot of space
cd -
exit 0
```